# Clicking item in frameset

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm trying to click on a link in a table on a form within a frameset, and having a hard time getting puppeteer to find the element, it's being loaded in a frame from  `rightmiddle.location.href = &quot;rtr?act=wcreports.WkstaAll&amp;sum=all&amp;sess=-63f78e5e:17b983a97cf:6d89&amp;edit=&quot;;`                  , any thoughts is there a way to click just based on page X/Y coordinates ?

**Full code:**

```
const puppeteer  = require('puppeteer');
(async () => { 
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, ignoreHTTPSErrors: true, width: 1930, height: 650 });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://example.local:444/zenworks/jsp/fw/internal/Login.jsp')
    await page.type("*[name='username']", 'USER' ,  {delay:1});
    await page.type("*[name='password']", 'PASS' ,  {delay:1});
    await page.click('#loginButton');
    await page.waitForSelector('*[id="ZENworksForm"]');
    await page.click("body > form:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(10) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > table:nth-child(11) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)");
    await page.waitForSelector("#mainPage__ctrl20a__inventoryReports_inventoryReports_dataGrid_row0 > td:nth-child(2) > a");
    await page.click('#mainPage__ctrl20a__inventoryReports_inventoryReports_dataGrid_row0 > td:nth-child(2) > a');   
    await page.waitForSelector("#mainPage__ctrl20a_reportControl_dataGrid_row0 > td:nth-child(2) > a");
    await page.click('#mainPage__ctrl20a_reportControl_dataGrid_row0 > td:nth-child(2) > a');  
    
    //this is the section that isn't clicking
    await page.waitForSelector("td[class='summarydata'] a[class='hyperlinkclick']");
    await page.click('#ScrollingTable > tr.summaryrow > td:nth-child(2) > span > a');    
})();
```

**Frameset:**

```
<frameset framespacing="0" class="treeframeset" rows="60,*" name="topfs" id="topfs" border="0" onload="">
```

**Form:**

```
<form action="rtr" method="post" name="input" id="input">
```

**Table:**

```
<table id="ReportTable" class="datatablemoz" style="width:100%">
```

**Link:**

```
<a class="hyperlinkclick" onclick="NewReport('wcreports.WkstaListAll','','&amp;grp=AccountId&amp;sum=all&amp;nogrp2=yes')">1,096</a>
```

**link's Selector:**

```
#ScrollingTable > tr.summaryrow > td:nth-child(2) > span > a
```

**Page HTML**

```
<frameset framespacing="0" class="treeframeset" rows="60,*" name="topfs" id="topfs" border="0" onload="">
<frame marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" border="0" frameborder="0" class="topframe" noresize="true" scrolling="no" name="top" src="./question_files/rtr.html">
<frameset framespacing="0" border="0" class="treeframeset" rows="*,36px" onload=" 
                dynamicTitle();
                 
                   rightmiddle.location.href = &quot;rtr?act=wcreports.WkstaAll&amp;sum=all&amp;sess=-63f78e5e:17b983a97cf:6d89&amp;edit=&quot;;                  
              ">
<frame marginwidth="8" marginheight="0" frameborder="1" class="rightframe" scrolling="auto" name="rightmiddle">
<frame marginwidth="8" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" class="rightframe" scrolling="no" name="rightbottom" src="./question_files/rtr(1).html">
</frameset>
</frameset>
```

Comment: Please put your complete code. Segmented like this doesn't help

Comment: @MannyAlvarado - I've added the full code, and the relevant html section